# nodemon installed but not working on centos

Tags: javascript, node.js, centos, nodemon

Hi I have installed the nodemon in my linux machine and set it in my path also.

```
[root@10-0-2-15 ~]# echo $PATH
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/lib/node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js:/root/bin
```

When I run `nodemon` command then it says

```
[root@10-0-2-15 ~]# nodemon
-bash: nodemon: command not found
[root@10-0-2-15 ~]#
```

Does anyone know what is the issue ?

Comment: Have you installed nodemon globally using `npm i nodemon -g` ? You can also check `/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.3/bin` folder, there should be a file named `./nodemon`

Comment: yes there is file `nodemon.js` but when I run `nodemon` then it says -bash: nodemon: command not found

Comment: There should be a file `./nodemon` without extension (.js)